# Requesting Formula for 4-days work and 4-days off including weekends to schedule tasks

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

Experts,

I need help in formulating the below example for 4-days work and 4-days off based on hours scheduled. I'm able to do for straight days.  Please see the details below.

Formulae Used

in cell G9=`=IF(E9="","",IF(I9=0,F9+I9, IF(AND($I9<>$I8,$I9-$I8>1,$J9>0),($F9+($E9/8)), IF(AND($I9<>$I8,J9>0),$F9+1, IF(AND($I9<>$I8,$I9-$I8>1,$J9=0),($F9+($E9/8)-1), IF(AND($I9<>$I8,J9=0),$F9, IF(AND($I9=$I8,J9>0),$F9, IF(AND($I10<>$I9,J9>0),(F9+I9)-1,$F9))))))))`

in cell F10=`=IF(AND($H10<>$H9,$J9=0),$G9+1,$G9)`

and the helper columns H,I and J contains below formulae

In cell H9=`=IF(E9="","",SUM(H8,E9))` its the running sum

In Cell I9 = `=IF(H9="","",QUOTIENT(H9,8))`

In cell J9 = `=IF(H9="","",MOD(H9,8))`

[image]

I want to calculate the dates based on the hours worked daily.
8-hrs worked is considered 1-day, after scheduling 4-working days, the next schedule date will be assigned after 4-off days .

I'm looking for the formula during scheduling if 4-days completed (32hrs) then the next date for scheduling should be after 4-off days. see the below the required output.

**manual input of Start Date and daily hours worked**.

Please have look at it.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On row 12, are you saying that the person works 6 hours during the period Sat 4-Jul-20 to Thu 9-Jul-20? How is the finish date calculated from the hours?

Comment: @FlexYourData the person actually won't work 6 hours on Sat 4-Jul-20. If you look at row 9 Fri 03/Jul/20, the task scheduled for 4 hours, and he has another task for 6 hours. So, he will work only 8 hours on Fri 03/Jul/20 and remaining 02 hours + 04 hours on row 11 will be on Sat 04/Jul/20. On row 12, the task he is assigned will take 06 hours to complete, In actual, only 2 hours were left for Saturday to mark it a complete day. In total, now he has completed 4-work days and remaining 4 hours for the task on row 12 will be after 04 days off. and it will be Thu 09/Jul/2020.

Comment: @FlexYourData I've modified the question, with half of the solution i figured out...any help?

Comment: Trying to work something up but I need to step away for a bit. I'll continue later.

Answer (score 1):

I don't do a lot of work with datetime math in Excel, so this was a learning experience for me.

I think the easiest is to include a counter column that keeps track of how many hours the person has been "on", then you can use this for "End" starting in C2 in the image:

```
=B2+QUOTIENT(HOUR(B2)+A2-1,8)+QUOTIENT(HOUR(B2)+A2-1,32)*4+TIME(A2,0,0)-TIME(8*QUOTIENT(HOUR(B2)+A2-1,8),0,0)
```

And this for start, starting in cell B3 in the image:

```
=IF(HOUR(C2)<8,C2,C2+1-TIME(8,0,0))+IF(D2>D3,4,0)
```

I found it useful to use custom format strings for Start:

```
[$-en-US]m/d/yy - h" hours worked so far"
```

And for End:

```
[$-en-US]m/d/yy - h" hours worked"
```

You can change these format strings to be appropriate to your locale.

The formula for the counter column is just:

```
=IF(D2+A3>32,D2+A3-32,D2+A3)
```

Except on row 2, where it's simply:

```
=A2
```

[image]

The reason for the complexity in the calculation of "End" is to allow for any number of hours. After each 8 hours, the day must increment by 1 with `QUOTIENT(HOUR(B2)+A2-1,8)`. Additionally, after each 32 hours, the day must increment by 4 with `QUOTIENT(HOUR(B2)+A2-1,32)*4`.

Comment: Firstly thank you for spending you precious time. I have tested and found only one discrepancy. IF in A2 to A4 we put 8hours, A5 =2 and A6=8 then up to A5 total of 26 hours counted, still 6 hours left to have complete 32hrs/ 4days. If in A6 I put 8 then the "Start date" skips 4 days, actually it should not because still 32 hours are not completed. in this case only End date should have 4 days added to it.  I hope you get my point. thanks again for your support.

Comment: You're right. I'll look into it some time today and come back with an edit.

Comment: any update dear ?